# printing age in descending order using array and functions in c

Tags: c

I'm having trouble printing age in descending order and second lowest age using array and functionin c.
I can input the age but I can't print the elements of the array.And i need to solve this question with parameters.

````
#include<stdio.h>
void read(int[],int);
void age(int[],int);
int main()
{
    int arr[20],s;
    read(arr,s);
    age(arr,s);
}
void read(int arr[20],int s)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter number of students:");
    scanf("%d",&s);
    printf("Enter age of %d sutdents:\n",s);
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        printf("Age of student %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
}
void age(int arr[20],int s)
{
    int i,j,a;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                a=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=a;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The ages in descending order are:\n");
    for(i=s;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
}```
````

Comment: instead of sending `s` by value to `read`, try pointer. The `s` in main function doesn't update otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void read(int[],int);
void age(int[],int);
int main()
{
 int arr[20],s;
 read(arr,s);
 //age(arr,s); //changed here
 }
 void read(int arr[20],int s)
 {
  int i;
  printf("Enter number of students:");
  scanf("%d",&s);
   printf("Enter age of %d sutdents:\n",s);
   for(i=0;i<s;i++)
   {
    printf("Age of student %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

     age(arr,s); //changed here
 }
void age(int arr[20],int s)
{

int i,j,a;
for(i=0;i<s;i++) //changed here
{
    for(j=i+1;j<s;j++) //changed here
    {
        if(arr[i]>arr[j])
        {
            a=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=a;
        }
    }
}
printf("The ages in descending order are:\n");
for(i=s-1;i>=0;i--) //changed here
{
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

}

Hope you understand.Thanks